# Existence of specific function

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I'm looking for some counterexample and would like to construct a function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that is in $L^1\cap L^2$ such that $$\int f(x)\log{f(x)}~dx=\pm\infty.$$
I don't care wheter $\infty$ or $-\infty$. Does somethink like this exist. I'm really bad at guessing such function but I don't see a reason why the integral should converge :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are such functions, one can take a bounded function that is just barely integrable, or a function that has a just barely square-integrable singularity (or both), so that multiplication with the logarithm pushes it over the boundary, for example

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}\quad 0 &, x \leqslant 3\\ \frac{1}{x(\log x)^2} &, x > 3 \end{cases}$$

is such a function. If you don't want to posit $f(x)\log f(x) = 0$ for $f(x) = 0$, add a small positive function to it, for example $e^{-x^2}$.

Comment: Thank you! I hope I manage to construct something like this the next time I need it. If one in addition requests that for example $\int f(x) log(1+|x|) dx$ converges, are there still such examples? I got the feeling, that the answer to that is no.

Comment: For $L^1$, you can do that by choosing a different strategy. Narrow high peaks. For $n > 0$, let $\varepsilon n = n^{-3/2}e^{-n}$. Let $f(x) = e^n$ for $n < x < n +\varepsilon_n$, and $f(x) = 0$ elsewhere. Then multiplying with $\log (1+\lvert x\rvert)$ leads to $\approx \sum \frac{\log n}{n^{3/2}}$, and multiplying with $\log f(x)$ leads to $\approx \sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$. But that doesn't work for $f \in L^1\cap L^2$, I don't see how that could be done, if at all.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
\int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{dx}{x(\log x)^a}=\frac{(\log x)^{1-a}}{1-a}\bigg\vert_{2}^{\infty}=\frac{(\log 2)^{1-a}}{a-1}
$$
for $a>1$, but the integral diverges for $a<1$.  So if you let
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}0 & & (x<2) \\ x^{-1}(\log x)^{-3/2} & & (x \ge 2),\end{cases}
$$
then the integrals of $|f(x)|$ and $|f(x)|^2$ will converge, but the integral of $f(x)\log f(x)$ (with its extra factor of $\log x$) will diverge.